# Using embedded CSS in Mail

Tags: java, html, css, email, gmail

I am Generating and sending Mailer using Servlet by replacing placeholders in Mail Template.Can I Use embedded style in Email for Styling as Below instead of inline styling

I am using a Newsletter email which has three place holder for Header Image, Email Body and Email Footer.Now the problem is since the Header Image is with in a anchor tag I am getting a border around the Image.

1. Is it Possible to get rid of the border by using embedded css
2. Is there any alternate solution for this problem since the whole **###HEADER_IMAGE###** is replaced by Image tag rather than Just image source.

The HTML code is as below.

```
<html>
   <style>
      a img 
      {
        border-style : none;
      }
    </style>
    <table width="590">
     <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
       <a  href="#" target="_blank">
         ###HEADER_IMAGE###
       </a>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    <div>
    ###EMAIL_BODY###
    </div>
    <div>
     ###EMAIL_FOOTER###
    </div>
</html>
```

Thanks for Reply

Comment: you would also need to use inline css - some mail clients strip out any style tags as it could mess up their websites when people view the email - [here is a good guide on how to write email css](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/guidelines/)

Comment: What Pete said. Or simply use the attribute `border="0"`.